# Thanking somebody lots and lots

Tags: phrases

I've recently come across a sentence like this:

> I want to thank you lots and lots.

I was wondering if this is natural-sounding English or not. If not, may I have some other phrases besides "Thanks a lot" to express the same thing?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: It's very informal, overlapping with childspeak. Best avoided in most contexts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Answer (score 1):

It's much more common to use the phrase "so much" when talking about thanks, it sounds more natural and somehow more linguistically correct. But at the same time "lots and lots" is a very common phrase in British English that we use all the time, I don't know about in American English - I think it's more common for them to say "loads" place of "lots"

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to say a little more than "I want to thank you". Here are some of them: *I want to thank you a lot*; *I want to thank you so much*; *I want to thank you so very much*; *I want to thank you ever so much*; *I very much want to thank you*.

"*I want to thank you lots and lots.*" is similar to these and is acceptable but it sounds a little too naively enthusiastic, as if said by a child who wants to emphasise "lots" by repetition.